# Ansible apt "No package matching 'libgl1-mesa-glx' is available" but "sudo apt get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx" succeeds

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, apt

I have a task in a playbook that is failing. The task is as follows:

```
- name: Install Zoom dependency
  apt:
    name: libgl1-mesa-glx
    state: present
```

The output is:

```
TASK [role-name : Install Zoom dependency] ********
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'libgl1-mesa-glx' is available"}
```

However, if I run `sudo apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx`, this succeeds, and running the playbook works fine (because the package is already present).

This is on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, using ansible-8.4.0 and ansible-core-2.15.4.

Can anyone explain why this works when running apt, but fails when using the Ansible apt module?

The reason I am trying to install it is to resolve a missing dependency when installing the Zoom deb package. I realize I probably should be choosing a different package to provide the relevant library, but that is a separate issue.